# SQL: Selecting the min and max values but with combinations where there are more than 2 values

Tags: sql, max, min

Okay so i'm trying to write a query that returns the max and min of dates of things that have been repeated. So if a particular movie was made 3 times at the dates of 1982, 1999 and 2001, the query would return:

```
Title       : Min  : Max
movietitle1 : 1982 : 2001
movietitle1 : 1982 : 1999
movietitle1 : 1999 : 2001
```

since there are 3 possible combinations, there are 3 results. If a movie was only made twice then it was just show the first date, and the last date.

```
Title       : Min  : Max
movietitle2 : 1960 : 2006
```

This is the query i have right now, unfortunately it only shows the min and max and disregards any possible 3rd value. It also can't used GROUP BY since i'm not summarizing data:

```
SELECT name, MIN(releaseyear), MAX(releaseyear)
FROM movielist
HAVING MAX(releaseyear) != MIN(releaseyear)
```

Comment: how does your data look like in the database? can you give a sample?

Comment: I think you are summarizing data and you should use a group by...

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have data in a table called movielist and the data is something like:

```
Title       Date
movie1      1982
movie1      1999
movie1      2001
```

You could try something like:

```
Select m1.title, m1.date min, m2.date max
From movielist m1
inner join movielist m2
on m1.title = m2.title and m1.date < m2.date
```

I tested the following on a local MySQL test database:

```
create table movielist (TITLE VARCHAR(50), MOVIEDATE DATE )

insert into movielist values ('movie1', '2005-01-01');
insert into movielist values ('movie1', '2007-01-01');
insert into movielist values ('movie1', '2010-01-01');

insert into movielist values ('movie2', '2001-01-01');
insert into movielist values ('movie2', '2002-01-01');

insert into movielist values ('movie3', '2003-01-01');


Select m1.title, m1.moviedate min, m2.moviedate max
From movielist m1
inner join movielist m2
on m1.title = m2.title and m1.moviedate < m2.moviedate
```

And I got the following results, which I believe is what you are after (I have used dates instead of strings but the theory is the same):

```
movie1  2005-01-01  2007-01-01
movie1  2005-01-01  2010-01-01
movie1  2007-01-01  2010-01-01
movie2  2001-01-01  2002-01-01
```

Comment: i tried your solution and it seems to be in a different format, i put MIN at the front of my values. I'm using SQLFire

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by different format. My understanding is you want every instance of the same movie name where it has two or more different dates, and you want to see every combination of the dates of that movie. I tried the method added to the answer